# python binary file operation

Tags: python, types, binaryfiles

I am getting trouble working with binary file in python.

Here is what I want to do:
I have a binary file in which I want to modify a sequence by another.

The sequence to replace is 'ASBF' .
And I want to replace it by a number.

It worked just fine when I used python 2.7.
But now in python 3.3 there is a difference between bytes and str and I think it is my problem.

Here was the code I was doing:

```
#that is the number I want to put instead of the hexa sequence
number = 1703518678 
#I put it in an array
number_array = []   
number_array.append(number & 0xFF)
number_array.append(number >> 8 & 0xFF) 
number_array.append(number >> 16 & 0xFF)
number_array.append(number >> 24 & 0xFF)

f = open(fichier_bin, 'rb')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open(fichier_bin, 'wb')
for line in lines:
    f.write(line.replace('ASBF', struct.pack('BBBB', number_array[0], number_array[1], number_array[2], number_array[3]))) #replace ASBF by the number
f.close()
```

I tried other things to workaround the problem but I can't figure out how to replace a sequence by another in a binary file.
I would like 41534246 which is 'ASBF' in hexa to become 6589A1D6 which is 1703518678 in hexa.

**EDIT:**

And here is the error I get

```
f.write(ligne.replace('ASBF', struct.pack('BBBB', number_array[0], number_array[1], number_array[2], number_array[3]))) #replace ASBF by the number
```

TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object

And I really do not understand how to get through this.

**EDIT2:**
The problem I got was from the way I opened the file.
Now that I use with instead of just open, my program is working just fine.

Comment: You can use byte strings in python 3 by specifying them like `b'this'`.

Comment: FWIW, you should use [`with`](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) to work with files.

Comment: `"ASBF"` isn't a valid hexadecimal string. Are you looking for the bytestring represented by those ASCII characters?

Comment: And by the way, you can make the `struct` do the work you're currently doing with `number_array`. Try `struct.pack("<L", number)`.

Comment: @Blckknght yes it is what I want to do. Thank you for the struct fonction

Comment: So, when you run your code, what happens? You say you are "getting trouble" but that's rather unhelpful.

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry I did not put the error, I edited my message.